# Win32Com Error Running with Task Manager

Tags: python-2.7, scheduled-tasks, win32com

I have a python script that calls open an Excel file, calls a macro in the file, then closes. If I run the file from the CLI, it works. If i put it in Task Scheduler, I get an error from win32com.

Method opening the Excel file:

```
import win32com.client as WinCom

if os.path.exists(reportGeneratorFileName):
    try:
        xl = WinCom.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=os.path.abspath(reportGeneratorFileName))
        xl.Application.Visible = False
        xl.Application.Run("'{}'!Runner.Runner".format(reportGeneratorFileName))
        l.info('Start Sleeping')
        # Async mode of pythonw causes this to finish before the file is made
        time.sleep(300)
        l.info('Done Sleeping')
        xl.Application.Quit()
    except Exception as e:
        l.error('Error updating file')
        l.error(e, exc_info=True)
```

This is the Error i get:

```
06/04/2018 06:56:19 AM ERROR: (-2146959355, 'Server execution failed', None, None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LAW Report.py", line 846, in createReport
xl = WinCom.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 114, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 91, in _GetGoodDispatch
IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
com_error: (-2146959355, 'Server execution failed', None, None)
```

Now i am running 64 bit python 2.7 and 64 bit win32com while office is 32 bit, but as I said above, if I just run the script from the CLI it runs fine, just not from task manager. I am running this on a Windows Server 2012R2. I have tried configuring the task for 2008, 2008r2, and 2012r2. I also  tried with highest privileges. I do need this to be able to run whether user is logged on or not. Everytime I have tested, the user has been logged on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to
1) setup permissions in DCOMCnfg utility for user under which you're running -or-
2) change user to your desktop user account.

But first you need to get proper error code, not a generic message.

Pay attention that this should be considered as temporary solution since DCOM is badly supported by MS for automation as service. Consider switching to any library as soon as possible. There're numerous problems with Excel interop: you will have to reboot server from time to time, performance degradation with subsequent calls, you can't run Excels in parallel because of a good chance of errors, etc...

Comment: I'm using the same account in CLI and Task Manager.

Comment: Try to output reportGeneratorFileName to some log to see if there's any issues with getting file name from outside (spaces in name)

Comment: Also try to output to logs os.path.abspath(reportGeneratorFileName) (to see if issue linked to relative file name and invalid current directory)

Comment: The excel file is in the same directory as the script. The file name did have spaces in it, so I tried removing them. Still getting the same thing. I find it weird that I can run the script from the command line and everything is fine, but as a task its not.

Comment: Whats about current directory? Are them the same?

Comment: And how do you launch from scheduler? Do you launch script? Scheduler parses script, you know.

Comment: I run both form the same location. I give scheduler the path to python then give it a start in path for the folder containing the script and the excel file. I set the argument as the python file as this is what has worked best in the past. The rest of the script runs just fine, i have logging and database entries that prove that.

Comment: I can't help then... In my projects those endless problems with interop automation led us to buy SyncFusion license. Constant reboots and performance degradation in production servers costs much more then license...

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error of which my program can run from command prompt but not from task scheduler.

I solved this issue with these settings of task properties in task scheduler:
1. General->Security Options
   a. make sure same user account you used to run python/microsoft program.
   b. checked "Run only when user is logged on.
   c. unchecked "Hidden"

For 1a, I'm using DOMAIN\userid that I used to login my laptop/PC.

This is the only way I found in order for the task scheduler to run successfully. Hope this helps.